# High computation in probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Six men and some number of women stand in a line in random order. Let $p$ be the probability that a group of at least four men stand together in the line, given that every man stands next to at least one other man. Find the least number of women in the line such that $p$ does not exceed 1 percent.

Obviously:

$$\overbrace{P(\text{at least four in a line})}^{P_T} = P(\text{4 in line}) + P(\text{5 in line}) + P(\text{6 in line})$$

But first the counting Aspect.

We have lined up:

$$MMMMMMWWWWWW...$$

To get exactly $2$ groups of $4$ men,  we have choices:

$$MMWMMMM \space \text{AND} \space MMMMWMM$$ But I see that we could also have:

$$MMWWWWWWWWWMMMM \space \text{AND} \space MMMMWWWWWWWWMM$$

So suppose we have $x$ women, so $x*W$ total.

> Then I am confused.
>
> To get two groups of four men together, how many ways are there? I would say $2$ but that doesnt use $x$ or $W$ then?

Comment: When you quote a problem, please give the source. This appears to be from  the 2011 AIME.

Comment: Strange that men and women are treated as mere categories, and it is not very clear from the wording that "given that every man stands next to at least one other man" applies to all arrangements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are $x$ women. I assume them all to be the same, like you seem to do in the question.

**Case 1.** If there is a block of exactly 4 men, we have two possibilities.

---

**Case 1.1.** If the block of 4 men is at the end or the beginning of the row, we only need one women enclosing it. So we have the block $B$ consisting of 4 men and 1 woman, which can be at the beginning of the end. For the other $x-1$ women and block of two men, we have $x$ places. The block of men can stand anywhere, the $x-1$ women fill up the rest.

Therefore this gives $2x$ possibilities.

---

**Case 1.2.** If the block of 4 men is not at the end or the beginning of the row, we need we need two women enclosing it. So we have the block $B$ consisting of 4 men and 2 woman. Further we have a block of 2 men. And then we have $x-2$ women. We therefore have $x$ places to place two unique objects, this can be done in $x(x-1)$ ways and again the women fill up the rest.

This gives $x(x-1)$ possibilities.

---

**Case 2.** Exactly 5 men is not possible because one men would be lonely.

---

**Case 3.** If there is a block of 6 men, and $x$ women, we have $x+1$ possibilities since there are $x+1$ places to place the block.

---

In total, we have $x^2+2x+1$ possibilities.

The total number is the way to order 3 blocks of two men on $x+3$ places, therefore it equals $$\frac{(x+3)(x+2)(x+1)}{6}$$

Plus the number of ways to order 2 blocks of three men on $x+2$ places, that equals $\frac{(x+2)(x+1)}{2}$.

Minus the number of ways to place one block a block of six men on $x+1$ places, that is $x+1$.

Thus $$P=\frac{6(x^2+2x+1)}{(x^2+8x+6)(x+1)}=\frac{6(x+1)}{x^2+8x+6}=0.01$$

Solving this will give $x=594$.

Comment: (+1) A little doubt in understanding cases 1.1. I have:

$MMWMMMMW$ and $WMMMMWMM$ as the cases. But by $x$ more spots do you mean: $MMWMMMMW WWWWW...$? But those aren't $x$ more spots there are $x-2$ spots? Since two have been taken?

Comment: I have $x+1$ objects: The $x-1$ women, the block of two men and the block $B$ of four men and one women. There is one place taken by $B$. So $x$ places left.

Comment: Okay, but dont we have to take out two women? To make the pattern: $MMWMMMMW$? Since we need $2$ dividers? So we have $x-2$ women left?

Comment: That's exactly the difference between case 1.1. and case 1.2.

Comment: dang it, I'm messing it up. I mean, in **case 1.1**, now, we have the following, either: $MMMMWMM$ and $MMWMMMM$. So we have $x-1$ women left. Initially we had: $x + 6$ spots, but $-6$ for the men, so: $x$ spots. Now there are $x-1$ women and $x-1$ spots right?

Comment: No. $x-1$ women and one block of two men. The block of two men doesn't have to be in one of the corners! Hence we have $x$ positions for the block of two men and two choices for the side we plase the block of 4 men and a women. Hence $2x$ possibilities.

Comment: Mmmm.. This is indeed very confusing. Lets start decomposing from the beginning. We had: $MMMMXMM$ There were without anything being done $x + 6$ total spots. Then you take out $4$ men, we had $x+ 2$ spots left. Now we have left one woman, and two men and then a leftover $x-1$ women. $x + 2 - 3 = x-1$ spots! I still have no clue why you add back the $1$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26302/discussion-between-wythagoras-and-amad27).

Comment: Even with the new arrangement though. let $MM = L$ we have:

$LLxL$ and originally $N + 3$ spots. Take out four we still have $N - 1$ spots!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the men as $M, M,\ldots,M$ to get 4 aligned and no men alone you need to form 2 groups, one with $4$ men and one with $2$ men.

let $G(4),G(2)$ be the group with $4$ and  $2$ men respectively.

A favorable occurrence is of the form

$$W(n_1) G(4) W(n_2) G(2) W(n_3) $$
$$W(n_1) G(2) W(n_2) G(4) W(n_3) $$
or $$ W(N_1) G(4) G(2) W(N_2)  $$

where $n_1 + n_2 +n_3 = N_1+N_2 = N$ the number of women.

Let's count how many favourable occurrences ($F$) there are. Since we are double counting ($G(4)G(2) = G(2)G(4)$) we get
$$F = {N+2 \choose 2} + {N+2 \choose 2} - {N+1 \choose 1} $$

The total of arrangements ($T$) when men are never apart is given by

the cases
$$ W(n_1)G(2)W(n_2)G(2) W(n_3)G(2) W(n_4) $$
or
$$ W(n_1)G(3)W(n_2)G(3) W(n_3)$$
 Since we are double counting ($G(2)G(2)G(2) = G(3)G(3)$) we get
$$ T = {N+3 \choose 3} +  {N+2 \choose 2} - {N+1 \choose 1}$$

Calculate the probability of success(p)

$$p = \frac{F}{T}  = \frac{{N+2 \choose 2} + {N+2 \choose 2} + {N+1 \choose 1}}{{N+3 \choose 3} +  {N+2 \choose 2} - {N+1 \choose 1}} $$

and check for which value of $N$ this is smaller than $1\%$.

$N = 594$

Comment: How is $\binom{N + 2}{2}$ a favorable arrangement? For which case does this apply/

Comment: $N+2$ places for $N$ women and $2$ groups of men. It does not apply for the case when the two group of men are together.

Comment: (+1), but aren't the groups of men considered different spaces? one space per person?

Comment: You could think that way, but for me the best way to see is to consider them as a whole chunk. The entire group becomes a single space.

Comment: then why in the end you count $N + 6$?

Comment: because the men no longer are bound to be together. they become separate entities.

Comment: but how are you allowed to change it in the end/

Comment: You are counting the total number of configurations, this won't be a favourable outcome, but a possible arrangement of the individuals

Comment: Yes, but $M$ alone isnt allowed though?

Comment: No, $M$ alone is not a favourable outcome, but it is a possible one.

Comment: Okay, what is your final answer? $N = 576$ was the correct one? Does this way get there too?

Comment: No, I found a different result. I found $21$

Comment: My answer is wrong. Wythagoras got it right

Answer (score 0):

Let there be *n* women.

To meet the criteria, men must either be in two blocks of 4 & 2 and positioned in two of the *(n+1)* **gaps** between women (including the ends), or in a block of 6 positioned in the *(n+1)* gaps,

i.e.  in $[(n+1)\cdot n  + (n+1)]$ **patterns**, having 4!2! and 6! permutations respectively, thus

$$\frac{[(n+1)\cdot n!]\cdot(n\cdot 4!\cdot2! + 6!)}{(6+n)!} \le \frac{1}{100},$$  which yields **n = 7**

---

*EDIT*

I took people as individuals, not as categories. Anyway, I am working out an answer treating as categories, and that in no arrangement can a man be left "lonely"

Basically, there will be *(n+1)* **gaps** (including ends) in which **clumps** of men can be positioned.

The favorable clumps are 4-2, 2-4 and 6.
The unfavorable clumps are 3-3 and 2-2-2

Thus $$\frac{2{n+1\choose 2} + {n+1\choose 1}}{2{n+1\choose 2} + {n+1\choose 1}  + {n+1\choose 2} + {n+1\choose 3}} \le \frac{1}{100}$$

[Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=[2*C%28n%2B1%2C2%29+%2B+C%28n%2B1%2C1%29]%2F[2*C%28n%2B1%2C2%29+%2B+C%28n%2B1%2C1%29+%2B+C%28n%2B1%2C2%29+%2B+C%28n%2B1%2C3%29]+%3C%3D+1%2F100%2Cn%3E0) gives $\ge593.002$, thus 594

Comment: The answer is $n = 59_$ five-ninety something

Comment: I think this is the version when all women and men are considered different.

Comment: Why shouldn't individuals be considered distinct ? These are not white balls and black balls ! Is "five-ninety something" the book answer?

Comment: @trueblueanil, no, I cannot remember the exact answer but I remembered it was in the 590's.

Comment: $n=7$ isnt correct, it is $n = 576$

Comment: I took people as *individuals*, not as *categories*. Anyway, I am working out an answer treating as categories, given that in no arrangement can a man be left *lonely*